# Can I share my google analytics result to someone else?

Tags: google-analytics

I work in a small company and we  - as many others = use google analytics to monitor how well/bad our site is doing.
To access this information we put the google account's details (username and pwd) and off we go.

I now want to share this information with one of my clients but I don't want to give him my google account.

can anybody suggest the best way or the best practices to achieve this ?

Many Thanks
Lp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you want to "publish it", you might want to extract the relevant data via the [Google Analytics API](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/attention-developers-google-analytics.html), which provides read-only access, works just like an ordinary Google Data API--this way you can serve it from your own Site without restriction.

That still leaves the presentation of that data, but at least you have complete control over it.

Comment: Thanks. 
That's what I want to do.
do you know how easy it is ?

Comment: well i use GA every day and all of the data i present (via a dashboard to my employer's Intranet) is collected via their API. Give me a few minutes and i'll update my answer with the steps required to connect and DL your data.

Comment: looks like all you can do is use their API then "re present it" or use some plugin or other (or helper site) to do the same.

Comment: Google Analytics API seems promising, @doug! However, how do we overcome authorization - only me and a few colleagues have access to our Google Analytics account; therefore, can authorize the request to get pageviews. How do I make pageviews available to the public?

Answer (score 1):

- the client can give you HIS account and you give his account view rights
- You create anothe rgoogle account just for read only access, give it read access to your google analytics and send the password that client.

I dont really see the issue here ;)

Comment: Thanks Tom. 
but I was wondering how to make them visible to anyone. 
Not only that specific client. 
Sorry I did not phrase the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  This is a service tailored specifically to allow you to define nice looking charts against your Google Analytics data and then embed them on to your site.  The service utilizes the Google Analytics API.

(disclosure: I work with EmbeddedAnalytics).

Answer (score 0):

You may now use Google Analytics [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/%20Google%20Analytics%20Embed%20API) for the purpose. Clients still do need to have Google account.